# Javascript: Finding the longest name from an array

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to learn javascript and am just beginning.

So I have created my own project. I have an array of Rivers and want to compare the lengths of their names.

I know it IS NOT written in code form - since I am beginning - I like to write in english what I have to do.

I'm not sure how to set up the if/else statements with this large a comparison.

***Can anyone help with Step 3 by pointing me in the right direction without spoonfeeding me an answer?***

Thanks!

STEP 1 - List River names
STEP 2 - List River names lengths
**STEP 3 - List the longest River and list the # of letters in the name**

STEP 4 - List the Shortest River and list # of letters
STEP 5 - List the number of letters difference between the longest and the shortest ~ Modulo

**/*STEP 1*/** - Done

```
var rivers = ["Mississippi","Delaware","Ohio","Sangamon","Black","Current","Chattahochee"];

for (var i = 0; i < rivers.length; i++) {
    console.log("An interesting "+rivers[i]+" River fact:")
    ;
```

**/*STEP 2*/** - Done

```
  console.log("The "+rivers[i]+" River's name contains "+ (rivers[i].length)+" letters in it.")
    ;
}
```

**/*STEP 3*/**
HERE I want to compare the letter strings to **find the longest name in the array**. I then want the output
to say “The river with the longest name is the X River, and it has Y letters."
But I do not understand how to set up the if-else statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rivers.length; i++) {


If A.length > B.length Keep A else keep B

If A.length > C.length Keep A else keep C
If B.length > C.length Keep B else keep C

If A.length > D.length Keep A else keep D
If B.length > D.length Keep B else keep D
If C.length > D.length Keep C else keep D

If A.length > E.length Keep A else keep E
If B.length > E.length Keep B else keep E
If C.length > E.length Keep C else keep E
If D.length > E.length Keep D else keep E

If A.length > F.length Keep A else keep F
If B.length > F.length Keep B else keep F
If C.length > F.length Keep C else keep F
If D.length > F.length Keep D else keep F
If E.length > F.length Keep E else keep F

If A.length > G.length Keep A else keep G
If B.length > G.length Keep B else keep G
If C.length > G.length Keep C else keep G
If D.length > G.length Keep D else keep G
If E.length > G.length Keep E else keep G
If F.length > G.length Keep F else keep G
```

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of all those different variables, think about "biggest one I've seen so far" and "the one I'm looking at now".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you're overthinking this; just keep track of the longest one when you're looping. If you find one that's longer, update it. I'll even psuedocode this for you so you can see:

```
myfunc() {
    var longest = "";
    for <all your things> {
        if <thing>.length > longest {
            longest = thing
        }
    }
    //longest contains our longest thing!
    //you can get the length by doing longest.length
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list of rivers from the shortest to the longest:

```
rivers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
});
```

Then the shortest is `rivers[0]` and the longest is `rivers[length - 1]`.

This is not the ideal solution, but it's good enough for learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It allows you to iterate through an array *and* carry a value from the previous iteration to the next. You can use that ability to store the longest name, and replacing it when you come across an even longer name.

```
var longestName = rivers.reduce(function(longName, maybeLongerName){
  // What you return here, becomes "longName" in the next iteration
  // If it's the last item, what you return is the value returned by reduce
  return maybeLongerName.length > longName.length ? maybeLongerName : longName; 
}, '');
```

Comment: btw - remove the reduce's initialValue, and save the 1st iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use two variables. One holds the longest length of a name, the other holds the index in the array. As you loop through the array, compare the length of the current element with the longest name.

```
var longest_length = -1;
var longest_index = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rivers.length; i++) {
    if (rivers.length[i].length > longest_length) {
        longest_length = rivers.length[i].length;
        longest_index = i;
    }
}
console.log("The " + rivers[longest_index] + " river's name contains " + longest_length + " letters");
```

Comment: To clean it up, could just keep track of the index, and pull out the length from rivers[index].length.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 I like my style :)

Answer (score 0):

you should create a block of code that iterates through the array comparing 2 values. For example

```
var index = 0;
var length = 0;
var name = "";
for(var i = 0; i < rivers.length; i++){
    if(rivers[i].length > length){
        length = rivers[i].length;
        index = i;
        name = rivers[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can return that info.

Answer (score 0):

+1 @Pointy 's comment.

@Joseph the Dreamer 's answer is a very good one (the best?), but for a beginner it may be a little complex.

Think back to Pointy's comment. How would you do that? A loop. What else would you need? A stored value. And, finally, you would need to compare the length of the stored value vs the current value in the loop, and update the stored value if the current value is longer.

Now, Joseph's `reduce` answer pretty much does exactly that, but very elegantly (usually harder to understand unless you're used to it). Try to accomplish this with a basic for loop first. When you "get" the loop, you'll better understand the `reduce` solution (also, you may need to read up on `conditional ternary operators` to better understand the `reduce` solution).

Spoiler: http://jsfiddle.net/v7wvg7ns/

(I can't just link the fiddle without some code, so here's some code)

```
// Ignore this
```

Comment: I finally looked at the spoiler and then worked it out for the proper answer.  However - I thought I could easily flip some signs and get it to change to output the shortest river name. But had no luck. Is it because I am starting essentially with nothing -> var shortest = ''; <- that I can't get a shorter answer?

Comment: That's exactly right. So what I've done is change the default `shortest` variable to a boolean `false` so that I can check explicitly for that to assign the initial string to start testing against. Spoiler: http://jsfiddle.net/edLbxozh/1/

Comment: Gotcha... last question - why the alert statement?

Comment: Just for testing/show. I usually use `console.log`, actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function longFriend(arr){
            var long = arr[0];
             for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                const element = arr[i];
                    if( long.length < element.length){
                        long = element
                        }
                             }
                            return long
                                }

                var  friend = ["abir","abdullah","robin","abdurrohim","ali"]
                var longword = longFriend(friend)
                console.log(longword)
```

Comment: don't know, how this adds something new in comparison to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = ['John Michael Doe', 'Laurain', 'Smith', 'Jamie Neesham'];
const namesObject = names.reduce((prev, current) => {
  prev[current.length] = current;
  return prev;
}, {});
const index = Object.keys(namesObject)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .pop();
const longestName = namesObject[index];

console.log(namesObject);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```
 var amountOfLetters = 0;
 var indexOfLongestName = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < rivers.length; i++){
            if(rivers[i].length > amountOfLetters){
                amountOfLetters = rivers[i].length;
                indexOfLongestName = i;
            }
        }
```